# Angular UI Modal is opening under the IFrame with a PDF inside

Tags: angularjs

I have this issue here with the IE/Safari browsers, I have an IFrame with a PDF as it's content, and when i try to show a modal dialog it opens under the IFrame not above it, I tried to change the IFrame z-index/Position with no luck, and it seems to be an issue with the PDF plugin itself because I can see the IFrame borders behind the modal dialog

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

**I have an update:**
Ok, I am now positive that this is a PDF plugin issue not the IFrame, the IE put the PDF on top and no other component is allowed to overlay it

While i was searching I came a cross the PDF.js, it's very nice and doesn't rely in the browser PDF plugin, the only issue is that you cannot give it a stream to display!!! you have to provide a path to the PDF file on your server, which won't work for me

will keep you guys posted :)

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up using the ViewerJS plugin to view the pdf documents inside the IFrame, it's very simple and you can embed it in your application, mine was MVC, you also can pass a stream or an url to your document, here is the link for their website, forgot to mention that it's for free :)

http://viewerjs.org/